# ¿Cómo pasar datos de un DataTable a un List de objetos?

Tags: c#, lista, datatable

Mi duda surge al volcar los datos del resultado de una consulta almacenados en un dataTable a una lista de objetos.
Lo estoy realizando de este modo, y aunque funciona, creo que algo no estoy haciendo bien, ¿hay algún modo mejor de hacerlo?

```
public static List<Product> CreaWProducts(DataTable dtArticles)
{
    List<Product> loProductes = new List<Product>();
    foreach(DataRow row in dtArticles.Rows)
    {
        loProductes.Add(new Product()
        {
            id = int.Parse(row["CodigoArticulo"].ToString()),
            description = row["DescripcionArticulo"].ToString(),
            short_description = row["Descripcion2Articulo"].ToString(),
            price = int.Parse(row["PrecioVenta"].ToString())
         
        });
    }
    return loProductes;
}
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen varias tecnicas que podrias usar para convertir `datatable` a `entities` propias

Una forma simple seria usando `automapper`

[Mapping from DataTable to custom model with property names different than column names](https://www.thetopsites.net/article/54351968.shtml)

usando este librerias puedes mapear el `IDataReader`

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, Product>()                
        .ForMember(dest => dest.id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetInt32(src.GetOrdinal("CodigoArticulo"))))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.description, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetString(src.GetOrdinal("DescripcionArticulo"))));
```

teniendo mapeada la entidad solo usarias

```
var productos = mapper.Map<IDataReader, List<Product>>(dtArticles.CreateDataReader());
```

Tambien se puede usar el `DynamicMap`

[AutoMapper With DataTables](https://www.geekytidbits.com/automapper-with-datatables/)

asi no se necesitaria definir el mapping de los campos

---

Tambien podrias implementar usando `reflection` con `attribute`

[Mapping DataTables and DataRows to Objects in C# and .NET](https://exceptionnotfound.net/mapping-datatables-and-datarows-to-objects-in-csharp-and-net-using-reflection/)

En el ejemplo define el atributo `DataNamesAttribute` entonces puedes indicar en la class con cual columna del datable mapea

```
public class Person
{
    [DataNames("first_name", "firstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataNames("last_name", "lastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

por eso se usa el `[DataNames]`

Comment: Mas complejo, pero es la forma de aprender algo nuevo.Gracias.

Comment: bueno lo complejo es relativo, edite la respuesta y puse otra opcion con automapper, pero habria que probarla

Answer (score 2):

Tu opción es correcta, aunque puedes probar con [`Linq`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries), dependiendo de la filas que tenga el `DataTable` será más eficiente.

```
public static List<Product> CreaWProducts(DataTable dtArticles)
{
    var listaProduct = (from row in dtArticles.AsEnumerable()
        select new Product()
        {
            id = int.Parse(row["CodigoArticulo"].ToString()),
            description = row["DescripcionArticulo"].ToString(),
            short_description = row["Descripcion2Articulo"].ToString(),
            price = int.Parse(row["PrecioVenta"].ToString())            
        }).ToList();

    return listaProduct;
}
```